# Is it possible to use an LFO or other effect that does not retrigger when you hit a new note in Ableton Live?

Tags: ableton-live

I am trying to create an effect that does not retrigger when hitting a new note on the keyboard. As an example, I am trying to achieve the effect of the sound panning from left to right in a cyclic fashion, similar to the effect in [Donkey Kong Country 2 - Stickerbush Symphony](https://youtu.be/J67nkzoJ_2M?t=10) 10sec to 20sec.

I know I can play a melody, and then change the panning on the track manually, but I want to be able to play live, and still have the left-to-right panning effect enabled. However, I do not want to retrigger the effect when I play a new note. Is that possible?

I am using Wavetable in Ableton Live 10, with a basic Sine shape as my instrument, but I am not sure what to do next. I am also a beginner, so any hints to put me in the right direction are welcome

Comment: Look for a switch or setting that makes the LFO "free-running" or "monophonic" (looking at images of the interface, it may be the little yellow square with an 'R' in it). If you can't find that, sync-ing it to the MIDI clock (probably by clicking the note next to the 'R') may achieve the same result.

Comment: Great. It looks like it solves my problem. Thanks. If you post your comment as an answer, I am happy to accept it.

Comment: I randomly came across [this video on Youtube](https://youtu.be/WFP79JtVif8?t=67) and there he explains how the "R" (Retrig) works. Which is what I want to achieve. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Well I don't have Live 10 on my computer and was just giving general suggestions, so please feel free to self-answer the question. This is not against the rules here, and you'll be able to provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the comments, as well as [this video on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WFP79JtVif8&feature=youtu.be&t=67)
I was able to find what I was looking for. I added a small gif, illustrating how you can do this in Wavetable. There is a square with an "R" (meaning retrigger) in the LFO-section. Toggle it ON to retrigger the LFO for each new note, toggle it OFF to make the LFO keep running (which is what I want to).

Remember to add the LFO in the matrix view. I have added the LFO-effect to the Osc1-pos in the matrix, changing the position of my wave. You can see that the wave changes its position from top to bottom no matter how many notes I am playing.

[image: Retrigger in Wavetable]